# Jquery executes before content finish loading

Tags: jquery

I use load() to load something into a div named 'contents', and hide it before it starts loading. I wish that the div would only fadeIn after the contents have been completely loaded, but it seems like the div 'contents' would fadeIn even before the loading in completed. I use the following script:

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#contents").hide().load(loadUrl, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);});
    });
```

Can some one please aid me in fixing this trouble? I am currently testing it on my local server.

Comment: I'm guessing there are images in the loaded content that has'nt finished loading when the fadeIn happens.

Comment: @adeneo yes, that's correct.

Comment: Then you have a problem, and disregard all the answers below!

Comment: @adeneo should I add .ready() script to the document i wish to load to trigger it?

Comment: There are many hackish ways to solve this, but the only proper solution would be to somehow attach an onload handler to all the dynamically added images, or more specifically to a new image object with the same source to make sure they load, and then fade in the content once all the images are loaded etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below,

```
$("#contents").hide().load(loadUrl, function(){ }).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a browser repaint problem, giving a timeout before the fadeIn is called should solve the proble

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#contents").hide().load(loadUrl, function(){
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            el.fadeIn(1000);
        }, 100)
    });
});
```

You can also try using the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#contents").hide().load(loadUrl, function(){
        $(this).delay(10).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```